# Creating WorkflowOutboundMessage using Tooling API

Tags: workflow, tooling-api, workflowoutboundmessage

Is it possible to create an outbound message using the Tooling API (REST), similar to [what's described in here](http://www.sundoginteractive.com/sunblog/posts/creating-classes-and-triggers-in-apex-using-the-tooling-api)?

According to salesforce Tooling API documentation  i tried  to create outbound message using following code

```
 String json = '{"Name":"MyCustomObjectOutboundMessages","fields":
      ["Id","Action__c","Value1__c","Value2__c","sObjectName__c"],"includeSessionId": 
      true, "description": "Outbound message for custom object ","endpointUrl": 
      "https://myend-point.com/listener"}';


Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/data/v'+METADATA_API_VERSION+'/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage'); 

req.setMethod('POST'); 
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'OAuth ' + UserInfo.getSessionId());            
req.setBody(json);

Http httpReq = new Http(); HttpResponse res = httpReq.send(req); 
System.debug(res.getBody());
```

but it is saying

> [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

Comment: I do not see `/tooling` in your url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment here is a working endpoint for a WorkflowOutboundMessage

```
https://xyz.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage
```

Which gets the object description:

```
{
  "objectDescribe": {
    "activateable": false,
    "createable": true,
    "custom": false,
    "customSetting": false,
    "deletable": true,
    "deprecatedAndHidden": false,
    "feedEnabled": false,
    "keyPrefix": "04k",
    "label": "Workflow Outbound Message",
    "labelPlural": "Workflow Outbound Messages",
    "layoutable": false,
    "mergeable": false,
    "mruEnabled": true,
    "name": "WorkflowOutboundMessage",
    "queryable": true,
    "replicateable": false,
    "retrieveable": true,
    "searchable": true,
    "triggerable": false,
    "undeletable": false,
    "updateable": true,
    "urls": {
      "rowTemplate": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage/{ID}",
      "defaultValues": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage/defaultValues?recordTypeId&fields",
      "describe": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage/describe",
      "sobject": "/services/data/v37.0/tooling/sobjects/WorkflowOutboundMessage"
    }
  },
  "recentItems": []
}
```

Yes. I find that the documentation holds a lot of answers....

**Tooling API Workflow Rule:**

> Represents a workflow rule that is used to fire off a specific
>   workflow action when the specified criteria is met. Includes access to
>   the associated WorkflowRule object in Salesforce Metadata API.
>
> Available from API version 30.0 or later.
>
> **Supported SOAP Calls**
>   create(), delete(), query(), retrieve(),search(), update(), upsert()
>
> **Supported REST HTTP Methods**
>   Query, DELETE, GET, PATCH, POST

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowrule.htm

**WorkflowOutboundMessage**

> Represents an outbound message. An outbound message sends information
>   to a designated endpoint, like an external service. Outbound messages
>   are configured from Setup. You must configure the external endpoint
>   and create a listener for the messages using the SOAP API. This object
>   is available in API version 32.0 and later.
>
> **Supported SOAP Calls**
>   create(), delete(), query(), retrieve(),search(), update(), upsert()
>
> **Supported REST HTTP Methods**
>   DELETE, GET, PATCH, POST

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_workflowoutboundmessage.htm

Comment: I tried creating outbound message by following documentation, But it is failing with [{"errorCode":"NOT_FOUND","message":"The requested resource does not exist"}]

Comment: @Sujithkandamuri - see my updated answer